# Django trying to save value to database but value turns into NULL when i'm trying to save

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I'm trying to run a command using subprocess which runs fine and then it should spit out the value using a print function, which also works perfectly.

```
cmd = subprocess.check_output(["golemcli", "tasks", 'create',unique_filename]).decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
test = print(cmd)
```

This will print something like "`cc490086-d851-11e8-9ca6-a6389e8e7978`"

Now I want to save that into my database. I've created a Model which looks like

```
class Usertasks(models.Model):
    TaskID = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and this is how my views save the data.

```
r = Usertasks(user=request.user, TaskID=test,)
r.save()
```

But when I try to save the data from the print it turns into a NULL value? My Django complains about following Exception Value:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: myproject_usertasks.TaskID
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: But `print(..)` does *not* return anything, it indeed returns `None`.

Comment: Okay that's a newbie mistake from me I didn't know about. Do you know any other way I could achieve this then?

Comment: To add to what @WillemVanOnsem said: `test = cmd` will do what you expect. You can still do `print(cmd)` in another line, if you need that debug information.

Comment: Your answer actually lead me to me finding it myself. I can just pass the cmd function into the TaskID= field. Thank you very much!

Comment: @schwobaseggl That is indeed correct! Huge thanks to both of you! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `print(..)` itself does *not* return the passed value, it *prints* something, and returns `None`, if you want to convert the `cmd` to a `str`ing, you can use the `str(..)` constructor, or you can - given `cmd` is a string-like object, just use `cmd`.

Next your `user` is a `CharField`, not a `ForeignKey` to a `User` object, so you will have to convert that to a string to, but this is *not* advisable. I strongly advise to consider turning this into a `ForeignKey`, since if you for example later change the username of a `User`, then the `username` you store in the `UserTasks` model, will refer to a non-existing user.

You can thus construct (and save at the same time) a `Usertasks` object with:

```
r = Usertasks.object.create(user=request.user.username, TaskID=cmd)
```

But as said, it is not a good idea to store the username of a `user`.